# A non interactive alternative to makecert

Tags: windows, security, ssl-certificate, certificate

I have a need to create a self signed certificate non interactively. Unfortunately, the only tool that I know of (makecert) is interactive - it uses GUI to ask for a password.

My OS is Windows (from XP to 2008).

The only thing close that I managed to find is http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/125982/How-to-run-Makecert-without-password-window.aspx, however, it is still not good.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might install OpenSSL, which comes with command line tools that you can run with from a script.

Here's a Windows build of OpenSSL: http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html